# Bounded type parameters - is upper bound included?

Tags: java, generics

Reading this here...

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html

> *"To declare a bounded type parameter, list the type parameter's name, followed by the extends keyword, followed by its upper bound, which in this example is Number. Note that, in this context, **extends is used in a general sense to mean either "extends" (as in classes) or "implements" (as in interfaces)**."*

... but after doing a few tests it seems the upper bound is included. So I think the part in bold is not quite precise. The general sense here is "extends or same type" or "implements or same type".

Is my understanding correct?

To give a student-like example... Say I have this method

```
    public static <U extends Animal> void inspect(U u){
        System.out.println("U: " + u.getClass().getName());
    }
```

Then it seems I can well pass in an `Animal` object to it i.e. the argument doesn't need to be a `Dog`, or `Cat` or any actual subclass of Animal, it can well be just an `Animal` (I am assuming that `Animal` is not abstract of course).

Comment: That bolded section is simply referring to the fact that the language only uses the `extends` keyword in generic bounds, even if the bound is an interface, as opposed to class declaration using both `extends`  and `implements`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Right, that I understand... But that's not my point. Seems it also includes/allows the upper bound... I mean... When you say "A extends B" you don't normally mean "A is subclass or same class as B", you just mean "A is subclass of B". Here extends has a broader than this default meaning, that's my point.

Comment: It has to be said, they use a rather poor example in the documentation. If you want the `inspect` method to accept an `Animal` or any subclass, declaring the parameter as `Animal u` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full quote is (**emphasis** mine):

> There may be times when you want to restrict the types that can be used as type arguments in a parameterized type. For example, a method that operates on numbers might only want to accept instances of **`Number` or its subclasses**. This is what *bounded type parameters* are for.
>
> To declare a bounded type parameter, list the type parameter's name, followed by the `extends` keyword, followed by its ***upper bound***, which in this example **is `Number`**. Note that, in this context, `extends` is used in a general sense to mean either "extends" (as in classes) or "implements" (as in interfaces).

*To summarize:* When the upper bound is `Number`, the type parameter accept instances of `Number` or its subclasses.

*In short:* The upper bound is **inclusive**.